# Php mysql query and foreach does not work inside function; but outside function the same code works

Tags: php, mysql, function, foreach

Here php function

(Update after reading comments etc.)

Yes, `$db` is defined outside and above function

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass//, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

function vatRates () {
   $something = "test";
   echo $something;

try {
   $query_select_date = "SELECT CurrencyRate FROM 2013Currencies WHERE DateOfCurrencyRate = '2001-03-23'";

   $sql_select_date = $db->prepare($query_select_date);
   $sql_select_date->execute();
   $data_select_date = $sql_select_date->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }
 catch (PDOException $e){
 echo "<br>DataBase Error: " .$e->getMessage();
 }
 catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "General Error: ".$e->getMessage() .'<br>';
 }

   foreach ($data_select_date as $data) {
       echo($data[CurrencyRate]);
   }


}
```

And then call the function with `vatRates();`

In output get only word: test from `$something`. And php code that is after `vatRates();` does not execute.

But if delete `function vatRates () {` and closing `}` then mysql query and foreach works.

Why mysql query and foreach does not work inside function (what need to correct)?

Comment: Where do you get $db? Why don't you have error reporting on?

Comment: Are you missing a global $db at the start of the function, by any chance? When using functions, you have to specify what variables will require global scope.

Comment: `$db` is not defined inside the scope of the function: pass it as an argument

Comment: @LokiSinclair `global` should not be the first recommendation to resolve function scope problems

Comment: aside from the obvious missing `$db` parameter, is `CurrencyRate` defined? You probably don't want to fill up your log with 'undefined CurrencyRate using "CurrencyRate" instead'

Comment: @YourCommonSense I will update question with $db. I just wanted to place short code (not to read long code). And outside function code works. Does it means that inside function need to repeat $db? Will experiment... OK, seems starting to understand ($db need)

Comment: You pass $db as an argument to your function from wherever it is called, as shown in Alexandre Ouicher's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function vatRates ($db) {
   $something = "test";
   echo $something;

   $query_select_date = "SELECT CurrencyRate FROM 2013Currencies WHERE DateOfCurrencyRate = '2001-03-23'";

   $sql_select_date = $db->prepare($query_select_date);
   $sql_select_date->execute();
   $data_select_date = $sql_select_date->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   foreach ($data_select_date as $data) {
       echo($data[CurrencyRate]);
   }

}
```

call with vatRates($db)

Reason: $db is currently outside the visibility of your function, this passes it to the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
function vatRates () {
   global $db;
   $something = "test";
   echo $something;

   $query_select_date = "SELECT CurrencyRate FROM 2013Currencies WHERE DateOfCurrencyRate = '2001-03-23'";

   $sql_select_date = $db->prepare($query_select_date);
   $sql_select_date->execute();
   $data_select_date = $sql_select_date->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   foreach ($data_select_date as $data) {
       echo($data[CurrencyRate]);
   }

}
```

Comment: Recommend passing `$db` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Function must be return something, a string, a array, a bolean, etc..

Better is (with arg $db passed):

```
function vatRates ($db) {
$CurrencyRate = "";

$query_select_date = "SELECT CurrencyRate FROM 2013Currencies WHERE DateOfCurrencyRate = '2001-03-23'";

$sql_select_date = $db->prepare($query_select_date);
$sql_select_date->execute();
$data_select_date = $sql_select_date->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($data_select_date as $data) {

$CurrencyRate .= $data[CurrencyRate];
}
return $CurrencyRate;
}
```

To use it:

```
echo vatRates($db);
```

Comment: This is indeed 'the better way' to do it, it is no 'must do' though.

Comment: Regarding `return` here http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php read that ends execution of current function. What if instead `return $CurrencyRate;` also need `return $Unit;` and other variables? `return $CurrencyRate. $Units. $Etc;`

Answer (score 1):

```
function vatRates () {
   $something = "test";
   echo $something;
   global $db;

   /* Your sql code and foreach goes here*/

}
```

**or**

```
function vatRates ($db) {
       $something = "test";
       echo $something;

       /* Your sql code and foreach goes here*/

 }
```

Comment: Recommend passing `$db` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with you not accessing the values in the array correctly. Try changing the foreach to this

```
foreach ($data_select_date as $data) { 
  echo($data['CurrencyRate']);
}
```